# Escaping UTF-8 symbols in JSON/Object format

Tags: angular, typescript, utf-8, escaping

I'm using Angular and typescript. The way we set some label is as follows:

```
this.label(label, {
  markup: [
    {
      tagName: 'text',
      selector: 'label',
    }
  ],
  attrs: {
    label: {
      textAnchor: 'middle',
      textVerticalAnchor: 'middle',
      fill: 'black',
      fontSize: 12,
      y: 15,
      text: text,
    },
  },
  position: {
    distance: distance,
    offset:
      {
        x: offsetX,
        y: (offsetY !== undefined || offsetY !== null) ? offsetY : 0
      }
  },
});
```

I get the following output:

```
<g id="v-1098" class="labels">
    <g id="v-1099" class="label" label-idx="0" cursor="move" transform="translate(355.231, 331.832)">
        <text joint-selector="label" id="v-1100" font-size="12" xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="middle" fill="black" y="15">
            <tspan dy="0.3em" class="v-line">xyz</tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
</g>
```

In that case `text` is `xyz`. I would like to use a UTF-8 symbol like `&#x00ac;` but it does not work.
I guess it does not work because the structure of the label is as JSON, meaning the string is wrapped with single quotes.
In other words, the structure is looks like:

```
attrs: {
    label: {
      textAnchor: 'middle',
      textVerticalAnchor: 'middle',
      fill: 'black',
      fontSize: 12,
      y: 15,
      text: '&#x00ac',
    },
}
```

I believe this is the issue but I'm not sure. The reason I believe it is the issue, is because when I open the DevTools, remove the text and write `&#x00ac`, it works.
Also, please note that I do have the `utf-8` meta tag in the header.
How can I fix it so it will escape properly?

Comment: Not sure I understand. `&#x00ac` is HTML. Not plain text. If you want this character in plain text, use '\u00ac'. Or just copy the character and paste it: ¬.

Comment: JSON is a text format; what you have there is just an object with string properties.